# Javascript variable unexpectedly undefined

Tags: javascript, scope, undefined

For this block of code:

```
  if(!skipit)
    {
    var update_argument='';
    if (document.formname.fieldname)
      {
        update_argument=document.formname.fieldname[document.formname.fieldname.selectedIndex].value;
      }
    window.setTimeout('updatepcols(update_argument)',250);
       return false;
    }
```

I was getting an error in my setTimeout call that "update_argument" was undefined. When I changed the line where I assign it the null string value from "var " to "window.", the error was gone and the code worked. I would guess that there's a scope issue here, but I don't follow it. Why would update_argument be undefined in this case, but putting it in the window object lets me use it? (updatepcols is a function that updates pricing columns.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead. Using a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) in this fashion preserves the reference to `update_argument`

```
setTimeout(function(){
    updatepcols(update_argument);
},250);
```

I have a funny feeling the script you passed as *text*, when evaluated, executes in the global scope, i.e. outside the local scope in which `update_argument` is declared.

```
setTimeout('updatepcols(update_argument)',250);
```

Comment: This works because when you pass a string to `setTimeout`, it's `eval`d in the global scope.  When you pass a function, it can read the local variables.

Comment: P.S. It's good practice to *always* pass functions to `setTimeout`.  Never pass strings.

Comment: Basically, `setTimeout(codestring, timeout)` works the same way as `eval`, which means that it's slow and potentially dangerous (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)). The true power of JavaScript lies in its ability to do *anything* with functions, so make proper use of it!

Comment: All my organized training was in BASIC and Pascal, and I never used closure in either of those. It's a new concept to me. I'll have to read a little more about it. I have seen what I think are called "anonymous functions" in PHP that look about like that, but never used them either.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a scope issue or not, but altering your setTimeout call should do the trick:

```
window.setTimeout('updatepcols('+update_argument+')',250);
```

This fiddle demonstrates: http://jsfiddle.net/mLrqZ/

Comment: I upvoted becuase it was a direct answer to my question, but I'll accept a different one because it teaches the better way.

Answer (score 0):

Change your expression.  Should be written like this if you want to pass the local variable to your callback function:

```
window.setTimeout('updatepcols('+update_argument+')', 250);
```

or if you want to use a closure instead, then do this:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){ updatepcols(update_argument) }, 250);
```

Yeah, like the others say, using a closure is better practice.